# arm-non-eabi-ld: Argument list too long

Tags: gcc, makefile, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to resolve an issue with my project. In short, I have a variable in my makefile containing the names of .o files to be linked. The variable has gotten too big, and is now causing an Argument list too long error. The offending line in my makefile reads:

`@arm-none-eabi-ld -T layout.ld -o @$ $^`
The problem is the variable `$^` expands to be too large, and I get an error stating that "arm-none-eabi-ld: Argument list too long".

What I'm trying to do to resolve the issue is to pass the arguments as a file, but I'm not sure how.
What I've tried is:

`@arm-none-eabi-ld -T layout.ld -o @$ <$^`

`` @arm-none-eabi-ld -T layout.ld -o @$ | xargs `cat $^` ``

and also tried:

```
@echo $^ >temp.txt
@arm-none-eabi-ld -T layout.ld -o @$ <temp.txt
```

that last one I think has potential, but says "no input files".

Comment: typo, is meant to read:
@arm-none-eabi-ld -T layout.ld -o @$ | xargs \`cat $^\`
I tried escaping the back quotes...

Comment: I fixed the formatting. The proper way to handle that is to just add more backticks around the code: ```The command is ``cat `ls docs` footer.txt``.```. If the first or last character of the content is a backtick, as in your case, you need to add an extra space or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
@echo "INPUT($^)" > $(TEMP_LD)
@$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ -T $(TEMP_LD)
```